# How to create a list for a ComboBox that allows DBNull?

Tags: c#, combobox, dbnull

How to create a list for a ComboBox that allows DBNull?

I tried **int?** But **int?** is not the same as **DBNull** and the combobox does not work with the null value.

My datagridview combobox, needs **DBNull**.

I did:

```
var machineComboList = this.eMDataSet1.Machines.Select(row => new
            {
                Key = (int?) row.MachineID,
                Value = row.Description
            }).ToList();

int? nullValue = DBNull.Value;
machineComboList.Add(new { Key = nullValue, Value = "All" });
```

I want to put a DBNull value into "Key". Using **int?** does not work.

Related: [c# combobox binding and first null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934858/c-sharp-combobox-binding-and-first-null-value)

Comment: "How to declare an int that will take DBNull in C#" - you don't. map it to null (or something else). Also there are many such questions on SO. Please try searching.

Comment: Do you use EF for for data access? Can't you just use null instead of DBNull.Value?

Comment: @JamesBlond I tried that, did not work. It is for a combobox in a DataGridview and when I use int? it does not like it.

Comment: @MitchWheat what should I search for on SO - I have been hunting for hours.

Comment: @GrantWinney Two problem with the combobox - 1st it ignores DBNull values that exist in the DataGridView, they come up as blank. 2nd It gives an exception if I try and make it save int? = null to a field that takes DBNull.

Comment: How about "C# DBNull" ? or even "C# DBNull DataGridView" ?

Comment: @MitchWheat is right - the solution was to use a "DataColumn" and set it up with typeof(int) and .AllowDBNull = true

Answer (score 2):

`DBNull` is only intended for ADO.NET, to make a distinction between a missing value and a null value.

`int?` can be `null` -- this is probably what you're looking for. It can never be `DBNull`, as they are incompatible types.

It is rare to work directly with `DBNull` outside of ADO.NET calls. When reading from the database, you'll usually translate it like this:

```
object dbValue = ...;
int? intValue = dbValue != DBNull.Value ? (int)dbValue : (int?)null;
```

Or if you're a little more trusting of the data types returned, you can shorten it to this:

```
object dbValue = ...;
int? intValue = dbValue as int?;
```

Comment: Nope --- I am sure I am looking for DBNull, it is part of a combobox value/display pair and the data in the table has DBNull values in it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked ... am sure there is a cleaner way

```
        DataTable machineComboList = new DataTable();
        machineComboList.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
        DataColumn machineIdColumn = machineComboList.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(int));
        machineIdColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

        foreach (EMDataSet1.MachinesRow machineRow in this.eMDataSet1.Machines)
        {
            DataRow comboBoxDataRow = machineComboList.NewRow();
            comboBoxDataRow["Value"] = machineRow.Description;
            comboBoxDataRow["Key"] = machineRow.MachineID;
            machineComboList.Rows.Add(comboBoxDataRow);

        }

        DataRow nullComboBoxDataRow = machineComboList.NewRow();
        nullComboBoxDataRow["Value"] = "All";
        nullComboBoxDataRow["Key"] = DBNull.Value;
        machineComboList.Rows.Add(nullComboBoxDataRow);

        dataGridViewComboMachineID.DataSource = machineComboList;
        dataGridViewComboMachineID.DisplayMember = "Value";
        dataGridViewComboMachineID.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Answer (score 0):

`DBNull.Value` is not a type of integer, and it isn't actually `null` itself either. Instead, it is a private class which *represent* a null value.

You can clearly see this in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dbnull.cs). It is a public sealed class with a private constructor and a singleton (static readonly) value to it.

---

Typically, when you have an `int?`, or really, any null value, ADO.NET expects an actual value to be passed in. This is why you always see code that maps `null` to `DBNull.Value`:

```
using (var conn = ...)
using (var cmd = ...)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineId", machineId == null ? DBNull.Value : machinId);

    // ...
}
```

Now, on the flip side, how you want to represent `null` in your user interface depends on you. Thought, it doesn't really make sense to represent it with `DBNull.Value`, as that heavily ties your application to ADO.NET. What would happen if tomorrow you change to a different data store that wasn't sql?